# New Server Security Causing Issues To API Response

Tags: c#, api, apache, security, server

one of my old project/app was working fine for years, very recently client report that app does not working any longer due to API response issue.

it's just a get request to an API with some parameters..

till date (before issues occurs) it returns following response:

```
,,3,1669179307,0,
```

but recently it shows following response: (note nothing is changed in the source php/code files since project start)

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></html>
```

here is curl screenshot:
[image]

And here is the postman screenshot:
[image]

and when i check the URL in browser it shows the expected result, though when i check the devtool (network tab), it looks like page is loaded two times.. 1st one provide error (HTML/js) response (read marked) 2nd one provide the expected response (green marked), so, it looks like when it's called directly by curl/postman/c#... fails.. but as browser can do redirect it passed.

here is the browser screenshot:
[image]

i am sorry, i added several screenshot to give better idea what is happening.

and here is the URL in question:

```
https://simpleclienttracking.com/membershipmanager/remotelogvisit.php?locID=1&orgID=1&deptID=1&barcode=8346420
```

now my question, is how can i use the API code/file to get the direct response as i was getting earlier? do i need to pass any header? update/modify server htaccess file or what?

To test the error in deep, i have tried another URL from another hosting provider, in that case i am passing post request to an URL, and this server response slightly different thing, but looks like core is same, redirect!

here is the response from new/another server:

```
<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

so, it's looks like hosting providers has applied some kind of security for direct URL access?

thanks in advance for any upcoming help

best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In addition to the above, I would suggest asking the provider what has changed. It seems not to be something that someone will be able to solve until there is enough information about the problem. You just told us "Something has changed and that seems to be the problem.". I agree.

Comment: @MarkusSafar, thanks for your reply sir, what else information you need? i have shown the screenshot, in browser it works after redirect but using direct api call like usint curl/postman does not work.. and shows different response. isn't that enough?

Comment: From the data you've shared I would conclude that the browser shows your page as it executes the delivered javascript received in the first request. In the data there can only be seen part of the url. Did it change oder did the second request carry any additional information? I would propose to ask the provider WHAT they have changed and in addition I would recommend to capture the requests using wireshark and look for the differences in the first and second request.

Comment: @MarkusSafar, this is the url if that helps: https://simpleclienttracking.com/membershipmanager/remotelogvisit.php?locID=1&orgID=1&deptID=1&barcode=8346420